# How to pass parameters in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to train a network using tensorflow, I choose the "Inception_resnet_v2" as the net(from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py)), here is my train code,

```
def train(train_dir, annotations, max_step, checkpoint_dir='./checkpoint2/'):
# train the model
features = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNEL], name="features")
labels = tf.placeholder("float32", [None], name="labels")
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=80)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float32")
isTraining = tf.placeholder("bool")
#train_step, cross_entropy, logits, keep_prob = network.inference(features, one_hot_labels)
logits, _=inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2(features,80,isTraining,keep_prob)
# calculate loss
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=one_hot_labels, logits=logits))



train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNINGRATE).minimize(cross_entropy)



correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))


image_list, label_list = scene_input2.get_files(train_dir, annotations)
image_batch, label_batch = scene_input2.get_batch(image_list, label_list, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        print('Restore the model from checkpoint %s' % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        # Restores from checkpoint
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        start_step = int(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1])
    else:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        start_step = 0
        print('start training from new state')
    logger = scene_input.train_log(LOGNAME)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    try:
        #        Check if stop was requested.
        step=start_step
        while not coord.should_stop() and step<start_step + max_step:
            start_time = time.time()
            x, y = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])
            #y = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(y, tf.int32), depth=80)
            #y = sess.run(y)
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={features: x, labels: y, isTraining: True, keep_prob: 0.5})
            if step % 50 == 0:
                train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={features: x, labels: y, isTraining: False, keep_prob: 1})
                train_loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={features: x, labels: y, isTraining:False, keep_prob: 1})
                duration = time.time() - start_time
                logger.info("step %d: training accuracy %g, loss is %g (%0.3f sec)" % (step, train_accuracy, train_loss, duration))
            if step % 1000 == 1:
                saver.save(sess, CHECKFILE, global_step=step)
                print('writing checkpoint at step %s' % step)
            step=step+1


    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('done!')
    finally:
        #Request that the threads stop.After this is called, calls to should_stop() will return True.
        coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

but when i train the net, i meet an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scene2.py", line 245, in <module>
    train(FLAGS.train_dir, FLAGS. annotations, FLAGS.max_step)
  File "scene2.py", line 82, in train
    logits, _=inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2(features,80,isTraining,keep_prob)
  File "/home/vision/inception_resnet_v2.py", line 357, in inception_resnet_v2
    scope='Dropout')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1216, in dropout
    _scope=sc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 247, in __init__
    self.rate = min(1., max(0., rate))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 564, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
vision@Hjl:~/$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python3 scene2.py --mode train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scene2.py", line 245, in <module>
    train(FLAGS.train_dir, FLAGS. annotations, FLAGS.max_step)
  File "scene2.py", line 82, in train
    logits, _=inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2(features,80,isTraining,keep_prob)
  File "/home/vision/inception_resnet_v2.py", line 357, in inception_resnet_v2
    scope='Dropout')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1216, in dropout
    _scope=sc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 247, in __init__
    self.rate = min(1., max(0., rate))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 564, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

when i pass keep_prob and keep_prob to inception_resnet_v2.inception_resnet_v2(features,80,isTraining,keep_prob), the error occurred. How can I solve this problem?

when i train the network, i want to set keep_prob = 0.5, isTraining = True, but at the same time , every 50 step, i want to watch the model's train_accuracy and train_loss, so i should set keep_prob = 1.0, isTraining = False, am I right? How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate objective is to perform training and evaluation concurrently, and you are using the neural network implementations provided with the tf-slim library, then it may be easiest to follow [the methodology prescribed by tf-slim co-author Nathan Silberman](https://youtu.be/EYgP8j5QTww?t=1388).

In short, training and evaluation are performed by two separate processes, with the evaluation process pointing to a checkpoint directory, waiting (infinitely) for a new checkpoint to be written to that directory by the training process, and then automatically performing evaluation on the newly written checkpoint and writing summaries to a specified eval output directory.

To get started, you should take a look at the train_image_classifier.py and eval_image_classifier.py scripts provided in [the TensorFlow-Slim image classification model library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).

In eval_image_classifier.py, you will want to replace the code:

```
if tf.gfile.IsDirectory(FLAGS.checkpoint_path):
  checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
else:
  checkpoint_path = FLAGS.checkpoint_path

tf.logging.info('Evaluating %s' % checkpoint_path)

slim.evaluation.evaluate_once(
    master=FLAGS.master,
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
    logdir=FLAGS.eval_dir,
    num_evals=num_batches,
    eval_op=list(names_to_updates.values()),
    variables_to_restore=variables_to_restore)
```

with the code:

```
tf.logging.info('Evaluating %s' % FLAGS.checkpoint_path)

slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop(
    master=FLAGS.master,
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_path,
    logdir=FLAGS.eval_dir,
    num_evals=num_batches,
    eval_op=list(names_to_updates.values()),
    variables_to_restore=variables_to_restore)
```

If you want both processes to utilize your GPU(s) without running into OOM errors, you can allocate a fraction of GPU memory to each process by creating a ConfigProto object and passing it as the argument of the `session_config` parameter of `slim.learning.train()` or `slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop()`. See the "Allowing GPU memory growth" section of [this tensorflow.org article](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) for reference.

Regarding the parameterization of `is_training`, you will notice that the train and eval scripts pass `True` and `False` respectively as their arguments to the `is_training` parameter of `nets_factory.get_netowrk_fn()`.

Regarding the parameterization of `keep_prob`, nets_factory does not expose the `dropout_keep_prob` parameter of the slim nets. Instead, `slim.dropout()` accepts `is_training` as a parameter and replaces the computations that constitute dropout with the identity function. In other words, tf-slim is so awesome that it automatically "disables" dropout when you pass `is_training=False` to `nets_factory.get_netowrk_fn()`, as is the case in eval_image_classifier.py.

If you want to expose `dropout_keep_prob` to train_image_classifier.py directly (e.g. for hyperparameter tuning purposes), you will have to fiddle with the implementation of `nets_factory.get_network_fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/406ec641c944e57da5a7a80da63d20d262d2047e/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py#L291) method then it expects a python `boolean` and `float` value not `tensor`. So you need to pass values like,

```
keep_prob = 0.5
isTraining = True
```

instead of

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float32")
isTraining = tf.placeholder("bool")
```

## Update

But if you need to feed them on the training time, I think the easiest way will be editing the `inception_resnet_v2` method parameters at this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/406ec641c944e57da5a7a80da63d20d262d2047e/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py#L291) as below (remove the default param value),

```
def inception_resnet_v2(inputs, num_classes=1001, is_training,
                        dropout_keep_prob,
                        reuse=None,
                        scope='InceptionResnetV2',
                        create_aux_logits=True,
                        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu):
```

then you will be able to pass your `keep_prob` and `isTraining`. Hope it helps

Comment: when i train the network, i want to set  keep_prob = 0.5, isTraining = True, but at the same time , every 50 step, i want to watch the model's train_accuracy and train_loss, so i should set keep_prob = 1.0, isTraining = False, am I right? How can I implement it?

Comment: Edited the answer, now see if it helps or not